# Inserting HTML code with Flask

Tags: python, html, flask

Currently I have this code

```
boldtext = "<b>I'm bolded!<b>"

@app.route('/')
def index():
     return render_template("index.html", boldtext=boldtext)
```

and then in my index.html,  I have a section of code with {{ boldtext }} in it.

I had thought that once the page loaded I would see this:

**I'm bolded!**

Instead I see this:

```
<b>I'm bolded!<b>
```

Is there anyway for me to pass actual HTML code to the index.html rather than a snippet of just text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I actually figured out an answer to this fairly quickly, I tried it before but it didn't work due to syntax. All I have to do is import Markup by doing.

```
from flask import Markup
```

and then instead of defining boldtext as

```
boldtext = "<b>I'm bolded!<b>"
```

It's instead

```
boldtext = Markup("<b>I'm bolded!<b>")
```

Comment: How can insert variable inside a Markup sir ?

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for the [`safe` filter](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#safe).

```
{{ boldtext|safe }}
```